# Calling setNeedsDisplay does not always triggers drawLayer:inContext:

Tags: ios, calayer, quartz-core, setneedsdisplay

What can be the reason of that most of the time calling setNeedsDisplay triggers drawLayer:inContext: , but sometimes it doesn't?

(CALayer's size is not zero; opacity is 1.0)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc of UIView, if you call setNeedsDisplay multiply times in one drawing circle, there is only one trigger of drawRect: method. Because setNeedsDisplay method tells the system that it should update the view during next drawing circle.